# Unable to select the whole item when clicking on a checkbox contained in a listview

Tags: android, listview

I am working on a customized list view

[image: this is my apps screen shot]

here is my adapter class

```
public class MenubaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private static ArrayList<MenuItem> searchMenuItemArraylist;
private LayoutInflater menuInflater;
public MenubaseAdapter( Context context,ArrayList<MenuItem> results) {
    searchMenuItemArraylist=results;
    menuInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return searchMenuItemArraylist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               iewHolder holder;
            if(convertView==null)
            {
                convertView=menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list, null);
                holder=new MenuViewHolder();

                holder.txtItemName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_menuitem);
                holder.txtItemPrice=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_itemprice);
                holder.txtItemQty=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView_itemQty);
                holder.selectChk=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_menuchk);



                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else {
                holder=(MenuViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.txtItemName.setText(searchMenuItemArraylist.get(position).getMenuItemname());
            holder.txtItemPrice.setText(searchMenuItemArraylist.get(position).getMenuItemPrice());
            holder.txtItemQty.setText(searchMenuItemArraylist.get(position).getItemQty());
            holder.selectChk.setChecked(searchMenuItemArraylist.get(position).isSelected());
holder.selectChk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        //how to select the listview item ?
                    }
                });

 return convertView;

        }

static class MenuViewHolder
{
    TextView txtItemName;
    TextView txtItemPrice;
    TextView txtItemQty;
    CheckBox selectChk;
}
```

}

Now my problem is when I am clicking on the foodmenuitems the list get selected and the check box get checked.but if I only click on the checkbox then the list item won't get selected.thnx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep the track of the selected items, take one temporary arraylist of your object or simple arraylist of string in which you will add or remove the selected items.

**For example**

You have one temporary arraylist `ArrayList<MenuItem> tempList;`

Now in getview method you will have to do two changes

1. Check weather the current object is in the temp arraylist or not. If the current element is in the temp array list then just set the status of the checkbox to true else set it to false.
2. In the onClick method of the checkbox first check the status of the checkbox. If the checkbox is checked then just check weather the current element is in the temp arraylist or not if not then just add the current element in the arraylist. if the status of the checkbox is unchecked then check in the temp arraylist for current element and if exists in the temp arraylist then remove it from the list and after that call the `notifyDatasetChanged` method

Comment: I used this thing http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/custom-listview-ability-check-items/   If anyone is helped from this link please upvote my query.